# How to keep cell blank until date entered

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date

[image: Example data]

So basically, "INVOICE DUE DATE" is the SUM of D11+7 ("Date invoice sent out" + 7 days as this is when the invoice is due). However, when there is no date inputted in "DATE INVOICE SENT OUT" the "INVOICE DUE DATE" cell shows `07/01/1900`. I want it to show blank until I input a date into D11.

Also - the "DAYS REMAINING" column (K11) is made up of E11-B2 (invoice due date - `=TODAY()`. I again want this to show as blank until the SUM is complete.

Finally - 2day, 4day and 6day chase are made up of D11+2,D11+4 and D11+6. I want these to show as blank until D11 date entered.

Comment: I think something like `=IF(ISBLANK(D11),"",D11+7)` will do what you want

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - why do you post answer as a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your Formula should constructed like shown below:**

Formula in `E11`:

`=IF(ISBLANK(D11)," ",DATE(YEAR(D11),MONTH(D11),DAY(D1)+7))`

Formula in `K11`:

`=IF(ISBLANK(D11)," ",(E11-B2))`

Formula in `L11`:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D11)," ",(DATE(YEAR(D11),MONTH(D11),DAY(D11)+2)))
```

Formula in `M11`:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D11)," ",(DATE(YEAR(D11),MONTH(D11),DAY(D11)+4)))
```

Formula in `N11`:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D11)," ",(DATE(YEAR(D11),MONTH(D11),DAY(D11)+6)))
```

**N.B.**

- Format for cells `D11, E11, L11, M11, N11` is `DD/MM/YYYY`.
- Cell `K11` has `General` Format.

Comment: this is perfect thank you! - i understand the majority of the SUM - could you please break it down for me just so next time if i need to do it i understand the SUM i would need to do. Thank you very much

Comment: If D11 is already a date (and stored as a day count), why do you need to extract its year, month, and day and then turn that back into a date?  Why not just use D11 directly?

Comment: @fixer1234,, thanks for valuable observation I do believe,  since it's date value so get the accurate result I prefer to use such method. It's true that D11 can be used directly also.

Answer (score -1):

A simple IF should do it.

```
=IF(D11<DATE(1999,1,1),"",D11+7)
```